# Converting an input to float

Tags: python, list, dictionary, if-statement, casting

i am making a project that takes the input of something from an element, then provides all the necessary information back.
For example, carbon can be identified by `C`, `12.011`, or `6`.
The program i am making makes a list of those other details.

Currently I am trying to file the results from the list into their own variables.
I can get the system to read the input for a number, then use that to set the input as an int. How do i do that with float? I tried adding another line of code, but it returns an empty list using that 3rd if statement.

```py
    from periodicTable import elements
    
    givenInfo = input("please enter an the information you were given about the element, and I will enter the info for it:") #prompt for what they were provided
    
    
    #makes an entry of 2 characters or less capitalized
    if len(givenInfo) <= 2:
        givenInfo = givenInfo.capitalize()
    if len(givenInfo) <= 3 and givenInfo.isdigit() == True:
        givenInfo = int(givenInfo)
    
    #elif len(givenInfo) > 3 and givenInfo.isdigit() == True:
    #    givenInfo = float(givenInfo)
    
    
    
    #The proper designations for the data, for the start, it is all empty
    name = ""
    symbol = ""
    atomNum = 0
    atomMass = 0
    
    
    #Loop to run through elements dictionry and make list of the values there
    result = []
    for element, element_dict in elements.items(): #for (new variable made in for loop), () in (dictionary elements, but .items() designates just the values)
        if (givenInfo in element_dict):
            result = list(element_dict)
            break
    print(result)
    
    
    #Loop to assign each value to its proper designation
    i=0
    while i < len(result):
        if type(result[i]) is int:
            atomNum = result[i]
            print("The atomic number is:", atomNum)
            i+=1
        elif type(result[i]) is float:
            atomMass = result[i]
            print("The atomic mass is:", atomMass)
            i+=1
        elif type(result[i]) is str and len(result[i]) > 2:
            name = result[i]
            print("The element name:", name)
            i+=1
        elif type(result[i]) is str and len(result[i]) <= 2:
            symbol = result[i]
            print("The symbol for the element:", symbol)
            i+=1
        else:
            print(type(result[i]))
            i+=1

this is what my dictionary looks like for the elements:

    elements = {
        'hydrogen': {'hydrogen', 'H', 1, 1.0080}, 
        'helium': {'helium', 'He', 2, 4.0026},  
        'lithium': {'lithium', 'Li', 3, 7.0000}, 
        'beryllium': {'beryllium', 'Be',  4, 9.0121}, 
        'boron': {'boron', 'B', 5, 10.81}, 
        'carbon': {'carbon', 'C', 6, 12.011}, 
        'nitrogen': {'nitrogen', 'N', 7, 14.007}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looking for just positive integers or floats, you could check float in the following way:

```
if givenInfo.isdigit():
    givenInfo = int(givenInfo)
elif givenInfo.replace('.', '', 1).isdigit():
    givenInfo = float(givenInfo)
else:
    givenInfo = givenInfo.capitalize()
```

To check float, we would replace the first '.' with empty string and check if it is a digit.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly check the user input if it `float`. If it pops an error then pass the error to `ValueError`

```
    user_input = input("Enter a number: ")
    
    # Converting the input to float
    try:
        float_number = float(user_input)
        print("The float representation of the input is:", float_number)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid number.")
```